# Case Statement Not Evaluating How I expect it to MS Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to figure out why my case statement is not executing as I believe it should.  In the below sub, rs1.recordcount evaluates to 0, and the other 4 evaluate to 1.  To be sure of this I have printed the results of each recordset.recordcount both before the case statement is executed and also after it has executed.  However when I step through the code, I get the complete opposite of what I expect.  When I step through it, the second case statement `Case rs2.RecordCount = 0` is executed despite the fact that the statement evaluates to equal 1.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thank you!

```
Option Compare Database

Sub CheckDataTypes()

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Dual Year Carrier Report].EE_ID FROM [Dual Year Carrier Report] WHERE ((([Dual Year Carrier Report].EE_ID) Is Not Null));")
    Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Dual Year Carrier Report].PERSON_OID FROM [Dual Year Carrier Report] WHERE ((([Dual Year Carrier Report].PERSON_OID) Is Not Null));")
    Set rs3 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Dual Year Carrier Report].SPONSOR_OID FROM [Dual Year Carrier Report] WHERE ((([Dual Year Carrier Report].SPONSOR_OID) Is Not Null));")
    Set rs4 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Dual Year Carrier Report].ZIP_CD FROM [Dual Year Carrier Report] WHERE ((([Dual Year Carrier Report].ZIP_CD) Is Not Null));")
    Set rs5 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Dual Year Carrier Report].EP_PERSON_OID FROM [Dual Year Carrier Report] WHERE ((([Dual Year Carrier Report].EP_PERSON_OID) Is Not Null));")

Debug.Print rs1.RecordCount & ", " & rs2.RecordCount & ", " & rs3.RecordCount & ", " & rs4.RecordCount & ", " & rs5.RecordCount



Select Case intRecordCount

Case rs1.RecordCount = 0
    Debug.Print rs1.RecordCount
    MsgBox ("Please import Dual Year Carrier Report again and make sure to change the proper fields to text data type")

Case rs2.RecordCount = 0
    MsgBox ("Please import Dual Year Carrier Report again and make sure to change the proper fields to text data type")

Case rs3.RecordCount = 0
    MsgBox ("Please import Dual Year Carrier Report again and make sure to change the proper fields to text data type")

Case rs4.RecordCount = 0
    MsgBox ("Please import Dual Year Carrier Report again and make sure to change the proper fields to text data type")

Case rs5.RecordCount = 0
    MsgBox ("Please import Dual Year Carrier Report again and make sure to change the proper fields to text data type")

End Select
    Debug.Print rs1.RecordCount & ", " & rs2.RecordCount & ", " & rs3.RecordCount & ", " & rs4.RecordCount & ", " & rs5.RecordCount

End Sub
```

Comment: yes it was, sorry about that!

Comment: You `Select Case intRecordCount`, but your case statements use something else entirely (the `rsX.RecordCount`, which is not `intRecordCount`). You should read your code more carefully. It looks like you need a series of `If..Else` statements rather than a `Select Case`.

Comment: I'm not exactly clear about what you're trying to test for. Should all of the recordsets have at least one record? It seems like you just need to make the tested fields required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) use Option Explicit

2) declare variables

3) vba Case statement doesn't work like that. Your statement looks a little bit like SQL Server syntax and a lot wrong.

4) trick for young players: if you want to know how many records in your recordset then you need to access all the records.

5) [not shown] consider rewriting your SQL statements as "select count(*) as recCount from [Dual Year Carrier Report] where ..." and checking the value of rs1("recCount") , rs2("recCount"), etc.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub CheckDataTypes()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset, rs2 As DAO.Recordset, rs3 As DAO.Recordset, rs4 As DAO.Recordset, rs5 As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb

    Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Dual Year Carrier Report].EE_ID FROM [Dual Year Carrier Report] WHERE ((([Dual Year Carrier Report].EE_ID) Is Not Null));")
    If Not rs1.EOF Then rs1.MoveLast    ' required to force MS Access to load records to recordset NOW
    Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Dual Year Carrier Report].PERSON_OID FROM [Dual Year Carrier Report] WHERE ((([Dual Year Carrier Report].PERSON_OID) Is Not Null));")
    If Not rs2.EOF Then rs2.MoveLast
    Set rs3 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Dual Year Carrier Report].SPONSOR_OID FROM [Dual Year Carrier Report] WHERE ((([Dual Year Carrier Report].SPONSOR_OID) Is Not Null));")
    If Not rs3.EOF Then rs3.MoveLast
    Set rs4 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Dual Year Carrier Report].ZIP_CD FROM [Dual Year Carrier Report] WHERE ((([Dual Year Carrier Report].ZIP_CD) Is Not Null));")
    If Not rs4.EOF Then rs4.MoveLast
    Set rs5 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Dual Year Carrier Report].EP_PERSON_OID FROM [Dual Year Carrier Report] WHERE ((([Dual Year Carrier Report].EP_PERSON_OID) Is Not Null));")
    If Not rs5.EOF Then rs5.MoveLast

    Debug.Print rs1.RecordCount & ", " & rs2.RecordCount & ", " & rs3.RecordCount & ", " & rs4.RecordCount & ", " & rs5.RecordCount

    If rs1.RecordCount = 0 Then
        Debug.Print rs1.RecordCount
        MsgBox ("Please import Dual Year Carrier Report again and make sure to change the proper fields to text data type")
    ElseIf rs2.RecordCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Please import Dual Year Carrier Report again and make sure to change the proper fields to text data type")
    ElseIf rs3.RecordCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Please import Dual Year Carrier Report again and make sure to change the proper fields to text data type")
    ElseIf rs4.RecordCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Please import Dual Year Carrier Report again and make sure to change the proper fields to text data type")
    ElseIf rs5.RecordCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Please import Dual Year Carrier Report again and make sure to change the proper fields to text data type")
    End If

    Debug.Print rs1.RecordCount & ", " & rs2.RecordCount & ", " & rs3.RecordCount & ", " & rs4.RecordCount & ", " & rs5.RecordCount

End Sub
```

Hope this helps,
GraemeR

Comment: Thanks for your help, this works great!  I am actually noticing a way to potentially shorten the code significantly.  the entire procedure is supposed to determine if any of the 5 fields have no records in them.  So couldn;t I just say for instance

'Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Dual Year Carrier Report].EE_ID FROM [Dual Year Carrier Report] WHERE ((([Dual Year Carrier Report].EE_ID) Is Not Null));")
    If rs1.EOF Then
         MsgBox ("Please import Dual Year Carrier Report again and make sure to change the proper fields to text data type")
    End If'

Comment: Yes, "If Not rs1.EOF Then ..." works. The debug.print rs1.RecordCount, etc. statements are now [misleading] junk

Comment: My earlier note (on rewriting the queries) may give a better experience for the end user (note, I think I've got the expressions the right way round to mirror your statements):

SELECT Sum(IIf([EE_ID] Is Not Null, 1, 0)) AS EE_ID_NotNullCount
, Sum(IIf([PERSON_OID] Is Not Null, 1, 0)) AS PERSON_OID_NotNullCount
, ...
FROM [Dual Year Carrier Report]

One query result. Check each of the counts and concatinate instructions that the user should complete.

Answer (score 3):

Note that your `intRecordCount` variable is never assigned a value.

Each `Case` should be followed by a value against which `intRecordCount` can be compared. In your code example's `Case rs1.RecordCount = 0`, the `rs1.RecordCount = 0` first evaluates to a Boolean that will be True if there are no records in rs1; comparing `intRecordCount` and a Boolean doesn't make sense.

You could simplify your code as follows:

```
If (rs1.RecordCount = 0) Or (rs2.RecordCount = 0) Or (rs3.RecordCount = 0) Or (rs4.RecordCount = 0) Or (rs5.RecordCount = 0) Then
    MsgBox "Please import Dual Year Carrier Report again and make sure to change the proper fields to text data type"
End If
```